# BGPmon login: 'Password: incorrect access password'

Tags: monitoring, bgp

I have installed BGPmon following the manual. When I try to login by typing the address "http://127.0.0.1:50000/" on address bar, It shows "Password: incorrect access password" message.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Which BGPmon have you installed? is this the one http://bgpmon.netsec.colostate.edu/ ?
Looking at the manual for it access is over telnet not http